# How to display a recyclerview with Cardview in landscape mode

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a recyclerview that I want to show in the middle of the fragment `FR_RV_Level_Selection_Menu`. The app should only be displayed in landscape mode. The recylcerview consists of cardviewItems `rv_item_level_selection_menu`. Here is my current output:
[image]

There are 2 problems

1. The whole recyclerview is on the button of the fragment
2. The cardviewItems are not displayed in a correct rotation. They should be rotated 90° to the right.

Here is my xml code for "fragment_level_selection_menu.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the XML code for the cardView item "rv_item_level_selection_menu.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:contentPaddingBottom="2dp">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_levelImage"
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.507"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_bestResultThisLevel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"

            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_levelImage" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_CO2SavingsTotalThisLevel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_bestResultThisLevel" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView_gasSavingsTotalThisLevel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_CO2SavingsTotalThisLevel" />



    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

And here is the Java code for the Fragment with the recyclerview "FR_RV_Level_Selection_Menu"

```
public class FR_RV_Level_Selection_Menu extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RV_Adapter_Level_Selection adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    private ArrayList<RV_Item_Level_Selection_Menu> levelList;

    private FragmentLevelSelectionMenuBinding binding;


    public FR_RV_Level_Selection_Menu() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentLevelSelectionMenuBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        buildRecyclerView();
        return binding.getRoot();

    }

    private void buildRecyclerView() {

        recyclerView = binding.recyclerView;
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        levelList = new ArrayList<RV_Item_Level_Selection_Menu>();

        //Database query and processing to get the level information data;
        Cursor res = MainActivity.sqLite_DB.getCursor_TableLevelInfos();
        if(res!=null & res.getCount()>0) {
            while (res.moveToNext() == true) {
                int levelNumber = Integer.parseInt(res.getString(0));
                int bestResultThisLevel = Integer.parseInt(res.getString(2));
                int totalCO2SavingsThisLevel = Integer.parseInt(res.getString(3));
                int gasSavingsTotalThisLevel = Integer.parseInt(res.getString(4));
                int levelUnlockedInt = Integer.parseInt(res.getString(1));
                boolean levelUnlocked = false;
                if (levelUnlockedInt ==1) {
                    levelUnlocked = true;
                }
                boolean   isSelected = false;

                RV_Item_Level_Selection_Menu levelItem = new RV_Item_Level_Selection_Menu(levelNumber, bestResultThisLevel,totalCO2SavingsThisLevel, gasSavingsTotalThisLevel ,levelUnlocked, isSelected);
                levelList.add(levelItem);
            }
        }

        adapter = new RV_Adapter_Level_Selection(levelList, getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new RV_Adapter_Level_Selection.OnItemClickListener() {

            /*
            Define what happens when clicking on an item in the RecyclerView
            */

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                if(levelList.get(position).isSelected()==false) {
                    //Select the selected Level and unselect all other levels
                    if (levelList.get(position).isLevelUnlocked() == true) {
                        for (int i =0; i<levelList.size();i++) {
                            levelList.get(i).setSelected(false);
                        }
                        levelList.get(position).setSelected(true);
                    }



                }

             }
        });

    }//end method buildRecyclerView


}
```

Any idea what I have to change in order to adjust the 2 points? What I think is strange is regarding 1) I specify `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"` and `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"` but still it is not in the middle. And regarding 2) in the layout editor the cardview looks correct both in landscape and portrait mode. So I don't understand why in the actual app it rotates the cardview (whereas in the LayoutEditor it does not do it).

Answer (score 0):

To center the recyclerview in the middle of the fragment you can set the constraints to both top and bottom, or left to right of the parent

```
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

and add **android:rotation="90"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:contentPaddingBottom="2dp"
    android:rotation="90">
```

Comment: Thanks Saloni for your answer. Regarding centering the recyclerview: I tried your suggested code but it did not change anything. Acutally I anticipated that as when you look in my solution, I also set the constraints top to top and bottom to bottom. So this problem persists. Regarding the 90 degree turn: Actually when applying that on the layout editor, only the imageView is rotated and all other element remain the same. Strangely, when applying this on the emulator, it looks as it should. This is also the basic problem. There is a difference between the emulator and the layout editor

Comment: Sometimes, the layout editor in Android Studio might not accurately reflect the final appearance. Since the rendering appears as expected on the emulator,Trust the emulator's rendering for the actual appearance on the device

Comment: Thanks Saloni for your answer. The problem with the centering still persists. Your suggested approach does not solve it (as mentioned in my earlier comment)